# lubridate assigns unrealistic date

Tags: date, date-format, lubridate, date-formatting

I have a vector of dates in either `dmY` formats and `Ymd` format.
These are all dates in the last century.

From each, I need to extract just the year (Y).

I use the following code

```
library(lubridate)

sampleDates <- c(20100517,17052010)
result <- year(parse_date_time(x, guess_formats(as.character(x), c("Ymd","dmY"))))

result 
517 2010
```

However, I expect something like

```
result 
2010 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution to your problem that takes a particular difficulty into account with your date format. Let's say you have the date `20112020`, i.e. November 20th in the year 2020. For your function, it is not easy to distinguish which part of the string is the year - is it 2011 or 2020? The following code takes this difficulty into account, though let me mention that there surely must be simpler solutions.

**Code**

```
NonID <- grepl("^2", sampleDates) & (substr(sampleDates, 5, 5) == "2")
ID <- !NonID 

dates_normal <- sampleDates[!NonID] 
dates_special <- sampleDates[NonID] 

normal_years <- as.numeric(c(substr(dates_normal, nchar(dates_normal) - 3, nchar(dates_normal)), substr(dates_normal, 1, 4))) 
normal_years <- normal_years[normal_years > 1999]

special_years <- as.numeric(substr(dates_special, nchar(dates_special) - 3, nchar(dates_special)))
all_years <- c(normal_years, special_years) 
all_years
> all_years
[1] 2010 2010
```

**Explanation**

First, we divide the date vector into those dates which exhibit the indistinguishability (`dates_normal`) and those which do not (`dates_special`). Then, for the normal dates, we use the `substr()` function to extract the first four and last four digits of the string and keep only those values which exceed 2000. For the special dates, we only keep the last four digits because the year can't be possibly included in the first four digits for this date format.